# Можно ли упростить рекурсию?

Tags: c#, рекурсия, функциональное-программирование

```
public static int sum(int[] array, int index)
{
    if (array.Length == index)  return 0;
    else return array[index] + sum(array, index + 1);

}
```

Начинаю понемногу разбираться в рекурсивных алгоритмах. Однако в C# столкнулся с той проблемой, что приходится таскать с собой вместе с массивом еще одну переменную.В то время как в Python эта функция выглядела бы так :

```
def sum(list):
    if list == []:
        return 0
    return list[0]+sum(list[1:])
```

Можно ли на C# как-то упростить мой метод?

Comment: Можно упростить на python начав передавать начальный индекс как в C# вместо создания нового подсписка на каждой итерации. Кроме того, проверка в начале не работает, когда `array.Length` 0. Почему было не сделать `if (array.Length == index) { return 0; }`?

Comment: Можно `return array[0]+sum(array.Skip(1).ToArray())` по аналогии с Python, но как сказал user7860670 по памяти этот алгоритм будет неэффективным. К тому же в C# не зря существуют другие структуры, подобные List, Stack, Queue: `return stack.Pop() + sum(stack)` - передача по ссылке не пересоздаст элементы.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил. Понял вашу мысль, просто изначально казалось, что реализация на python более корректна.

Comment: Если уж зашла речь о фукциональном программировании, то там это называется "хвостовая рекурсия", а в императивных языках ее можно просто реализовать в виде обычного цикла с счетчиком и аккумулятором.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В примере с питоном используются списки, поэтому логичнее было бы и в c# пользоваться списками:

```
public static int sum(List<int> array)
{
    if (array.Count == 0) return 0;
    else return array[0] + sum(array.GetRange(1, array.Count-1));
}
```

Либо с использованием linq и метода [`Skip`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netcore-3.1)

```
public static int sum(IEnumerable<int> array)
{
    if (!array.Any()) return 0;
    else return array.First() + sum(array.Skip(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не таскать переменные, пользуйтесь значениями по умолчанию.

```
public static int sum(int[] array, int index = 0)
{
    if (array.Length == index)  return 0; 
    else return array[index] + sum(array, index + 1);
}
```

Как использовать

```
int[] data = new int[0];
Console.WriteLine(sum(data));
```

Если хочется еще проще, есть методы расширения

```
public static class IntArrayExtensions
{
    public static int sum(this int[] array, int index = 0)
    {
        if (array.Length == index) return 0;
        else return array[index] + sum(array, index + 1);
    }
}
```

Использование

```
int[] data = new int[0];
Console.WriteLine(data.sum());
```